# Display internal hierarchy of an Account (Company)?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, goldmine

I would like to find a way to allow users to build and diplay an organization chart for each account, companies we are working with and that are into our MCRM database.

MCRM users want to see, from top, to bottom, the internal hierarchy into a single view on the Account Page to have a global overview of the company structure.

One issue is that an employee, at a lower level into the company can be responsible of a department, and from here, we want to see that they are working under this contact.

Each combination should be possible and users should be able to add, modify entries easily.

In the feature, we will look for rendering the result under a 'Tree View'. What I just want to know now is how to set up this feature. To illustrate what I am speaking about, I draw a sample:

Company ABC (all contacts belonging to ABC company)

```
 - MR. X Big Boss
   -> Mr. Y
   -> Mr. Z
   -> Mr. W
           -> Mr. V 
           -> Mr. S
                   -> Mr. F
   -> Mr. O
           -> Mr. A
           -> Mr. T
   -> Mr. H
   -> Mr. Q
```

During my research, I didn't found subjects regarding this way to "work" with companies. Maybe their is an other "best practice"?

In the past, we were using Goldmine CRM and this was a default feature, that's why, now, some users want to have the same into MSCRM 2011.

Thank you for your advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing easy out there.  I did manage to get something working by modifying the solution [available here](http://mscrmblogger.com/2012/10/12/crm-tree-view-recreating-the-subject-lookup/).

Main changes are that you'll need to create a function to find the ultimate parent in the tree, then start the "Subject" tree off from that ID.  So you get the same tree layout whether you are at Mr. F, Mr. Y or Mr. Big Boss.  The tree is the same.

I then displayed the web resource on the form, rather than in a dialog.  After removing the buttons that is.  For completeness, I also added a double click action to navigate to that record.

I've since moved jobs and don't have the source any longer so I'm unable to post any code but I hope that gives you enough to start on.